# Is there a way for the MainViewController to know when a press IBAction function has been called?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview

I have a custom UIView which has a `press` method. This is a subview added to the main Google mapView. When this method is called, I would like to either call a function or set a global variable in the main ViewController.

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: One of the possible options is to use a delegate pattern.

Comment: ... or a closure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Built-in `NotificationCenter` API to `broadcast` notifications whenever the `press` method is called.

   ```
   let nofitication = NotificationCenter.default
   nofitication.post(name: Notification.Name("pressMethodCalled"), object: nil)
   ```

Register the notification:

```
nofitication.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(your_method_name), name: Notification.Name("pressMethodCalled"), object: nil)
```

2. Delegates: One to One. Read more here - https://medium.com/@jamesrochabrun/implementing-delegates-in-swift-step-by-step-d3211cbac3ef