# What is a good way to make references between each UIView in the hierarchy?

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, design-patterns, uikit

Suppose you have a UIView hierarchy like this

```
UIViewController
->UITableView
-->UITableViewCell
--->UITextView
```

Now when an event happens say

```
func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {}
```

You have a reference to the textView, but lets say you need an UI to change for the entire hierarchy and also data models, how do you do that?

One approach is to give it all the references, but it's very tedious

```
class CustomTextView {
  init(model: Data, cell: UITableViewCell, tableview: UITableView) {//...}
  func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
     //update model, update cell, update tableview
  }
}
```

Also I would need to pass similar references to the cell and the tableview.

Another approach is to set the delegate at the controller level. And then you have:

```
class MyController: UITableViewController {
  func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    //tableView.updateUI()
    //cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath...
    //cell.updateUI()
    //cell.textView.updateUI()
    //model.updateData()
  }
}
```

But then this leads to a massive view controller.

What is the right design pattern here where every view needs access to every other view?

Answer (score 0):

`NotificationCenter` and the `Observer pattern` - this will be the best option in your case.

> With NotificationCenter you can broadcast data from one part of your
>   app to another. It uses the Observer pattern to inform registered
>   observers when a notification comes in, using a central dispatcher
>   called Notification Center

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60385294/1244403

Answer (score 0):

Your second idea is closer to general practice, which is to use the delegation pattern making the VC the delegate. The VC's job is to modify the model based on external events and update the views based on model changes.

Looking at your comments on the delegate method. Mutate the model first. Then, the way to update the table view is to reload cells (either selectively or reloadData to reload all that are visible). If the VC controls other views that need to change as a result of a model change, it should do that, too.  (and it's just fine to do that in one or more updateUI methods)

"But this leads to a massive view controller".  Yeah, kinda.  One idea is to make them smaller by decomposition of VCs and/or by class extensions. Also remember that the model isn't just inert data. A common source of VC bloat is business logic in the VC that would be better implemented by the model itself (as a collection of objects, not merely data).