# How can I Navigate to a viewController from a collectionView's didSelectItemAt which is inside a tableView cell?

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        //let cell: HomeCollectionViewCell = homeCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "homeCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeCollectionViewCell

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ReadOrDownloadViewController") as! ReadOrDownloadViewController

        navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

    }
```

Here Xcode says " Use of unresolved identifier 'navigationController' "

The HomeCollectionViewCell is under a tableViewCell.

Comment: what class is datasource for collection view

Comment: you need to pass the delegate back to the tableViewCell and then to the baseViewController class in which you can access the navigationController.

Comment: @kjoe TableViewCell Class is the datasource for the collectionView

Comment: you can also use closure for this.

Comment: @Harish Holy! I still don't know how to do that. :(

Comment: the you need a delegate to the view controller or closure to transfer the action to the viewcontroller, only ViewController class have a NavigationController,

Comment: If you don't know delegate pattern then easy way for you is to post Notification at didSelectItem. check this answer for Notification Center.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60385294/1244403

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must set a delegate or a closure to the cell class to pass the action to the viewcontroller

closure:

```
class myCell: UITableViewCell{
   var closure: (() -> Void)?
```

since you set this class as the datasource and the delegate for the collectionView then rewrite this function as

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    closure?()
}
```

then in the viewController where you set the tableview Datasource then,

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.deque ....
cell.closure = {_ in
   let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ReadOrDownloadViewController") as! ReadOrDownloadViewController
        navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

for protocol is the same just set the delegate in the cell and call delegate function in the collectionView didTap item function